# Is $(\ell_1 , \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$ a complete space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I know that $\ell_2$ with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ norm is complete? I can't figure out for this set.

Comment: Observe that $\ell_1 \subset \ell_2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(f_n) \in \ell_1^{\mathbb N}$ defined by
$$\begin{cases}
f_n(k)=
1/k & \mbox{for} & k\le n\\
0 &\mbox{for} & k>n
\end{cases}$$

$(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence regarding $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ as the sequence $\sum 1/k^2$ converges. However $(f_n)$ doesn’t converges towards an element of $\ell^1$ as $\sum 1/k$ diverges.

**Conclusion: $(\ell_1 , \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$ is not complete**